# Cannot serialize my model in my View properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I want to serialise my model in my View, and to do so I use the following line;

```
var initialData = <%: new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
```

The serialisation I need for my View to work properly is the following

```
var initialData = {"EmployeeList":[],"ClientEmployeeSelector":{"SearchText":null,"SearchTextId":0},"Cvm":null,"TrainingName":null,"TrainingDescription":null};
```

But what I am currently getting is;

```
var initialData = {&quot;ClientEmployeeSelector&quot;:{&quot;SearchText&quot;:null,&quot;SearchTextId&quot;:0},&quot;EmployeeList&quot;:[],&quot;Cvm&quot;:null,&quot;TrainingDescription&quot;:null,&quot;TrainingName&quot;:null};
```

So instead of the quotation symbol " appearing, I get & quot; and this stops my view from working. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the colon syntax `<%:` HTML-encodes the response. Use `<%=` to write out the unencoded values.

```
var initialData = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
```

Comment: Fantastic! How odd that is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can return it as a MvcHtmlString and it will output without html-encoding the string.

```
var initialData = <%: new MvcHtmlString(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model)) %>;
```